# Does Azure Function method name matter?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am currently developing some C# Azure Functions. The naming convention I use is `Process[ThingIWantToProcess]()` like so...

```
public static void ProcessRequest([TimerTrigger("00:00:10", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = false)] TimerInfo timer, ILogger logger)
{
     // Do function things
}
```

A few days ago, all of the functions (currently, 6 of them) stopped running when they were deployed, but no code had been changed that I am aware of or can see.

The console, both locally and the Kudu console, say "Found the following functions:" and display all the expected functions; however, those functions are never run.

I tried all sorts of things, including re-deploys, restarting the Azure Web Job, and changing the contents of the methods, but still nothing fired. And then, I changed the name of the function, and suddenly it started working!

So instead of `ProcessRequest` it was now `ProcessRequest1`, and the function fired successfully. I changed the name several different ways, and all of them worked, but when I changed back to `ProcessRequest`, it stopped working again.

I can't find anything explaining this behavior in the docs or internet search, and I'm concerned it will happen again during future maintenance.

**Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, can you point me to some kind of explanation?**

Comment: Did you add the FunctionName to your method like this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#methods-recognized-as-functions And your are using Function or WebJobs?

Comment: Hey, thanks George! I am using WebJobs, but I did not use that attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heyy !! This is due to the lock behavior that TimerTrigger employs to ensure that only a single instance of your function is running across scaled out instances. So if you are using the same Storage Account for multiple web job's you will face this issue.

To resolve this issue I would suggest just create **separate Storage Account for you Job** and it should work as it is !!!

For more information please visit: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/614

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not matter.

> The FunctionName attribute marks the method as a function entry point. The name must be unique within a project, start with a letter and only contain letters, numbers, _, and -, up to 127 characters in length. Project templates often create a method named Run, but **the method name can be any valid C# method name**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#methods-recognized-as-functions

Comment: Adding to the answer for someone else to stumbles on this thread. You cannot have Double Underscore in the Function Name (the attribute part). Took me a long while to get it. As its usually the case with MS documentation. Its scattered and this thing was deep hidden into it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are bit confused about whether there is any Azure function naming convention. Okay, let's make it more clear.

**Azure Functions Are Like C# Method:**

As you know Azure functions are like C# method. So it is good to follow C# method naming convention here also.

But [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#compute) suggested pattern like this `<name>-func`

Example: `azureexample-func`

```cs
 public static class AzureFunctionExampleClass
    {
        [FunctionName("azureexample-func")]
        
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Read Request Body
            var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            //Extract Request Body and Parse To Class
            Users objUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(content);

            //As we have to return IAction Type So converting to IAction Class Using OkObjectResult We Even Can Use OkResult
            var result = new OkObjectResult(objUsers);
            return (IActionResult)result;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** You even can use `PascalCase` format like `AzureExampleFunc`. As there is no such strict bindings.

**Casing:** Case insensitive

**Function Valid Characters:** Alphanumeric and hyphen

**Function Length:** 1-60

**Key-Words Should Skip:**

Every language has its own defined key-words while name your function its good to omit that name. So that compiler never get confused about that.

**Make Function Readable:**

Though function doesn't restricts any mandatory naming convention but its recommended to use a readable name so that its be easy to understand what it does.

If you still have any query regarding Azure naming convention you could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions).

Comment: Those links seem to actually suggest the reverse of what you've posted as there it is being shown as func-<App Name>.

Comment: This naming convention is for naming resources on the Azure Portal, not the name of the function in the `FunctionName` attribute in the code.